# Error: module 'google.cloud.bigquery_storage' has no attribute 'BigQueryReadClient'

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

How to fix this error?

> Error: module 'google.cloud.bigquery_storage' has no attribute
> 'BigQueryReadClient'

Can't query BigQuery table and save results to Pandas DataFrame.
Packages:

```
google-api-core==1.23.0
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-auth==1.23.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-bigquery==0.14
google-cloud-bigquery==2.6.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.1.0
google-cloud-core==1.4.3
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpcio==1.34.0
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
pandas==1.1.5
pandas-gbq==0.13.2
pyarrow==2.0.0
```

Query:

```
def get_orders(bqclient,
               project_id,
               dataset_id,
               orders_table_id,
               datetime_start,
               datetime_end):

    query = f"""
        SELECT *
        FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{orders_table_id}`
        WHERE
            CreatedDatetime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('{datetime_start}') AND TIMESTAMP('{datetime_end}')
    """
    print(query)
    orders = None
    try:
        query_job = bqclient.query(query)
        orders = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(f'Error while getting orders: {exception}')
    finally:
        return orders
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it is using google-cloud-bigquery not google-cloud-bigquery-storage. How is `bqclient` created? Is it like this?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bqclient = bigquery.Client()
```

Try to find references to `BigQueryReadClient` in your code and remove them. Try to remove `google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.1.0`